# Need a smaller size for \sum

Tags: symbols, fontsize

Using the following code, I get a nice emulation of the calculator screen. However, I'm looking for a way to make the summation signs smaller. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\tsurd{\ensuremath{\sqrt{\phantom{i}}}}
\newcommand\txbar{\ensuremath{\overline{\text{x}}}}
\newcommand\sumx{\ensuremath{\sum{\text{x}}}}
\newcommand\sumxsq{\ensuremath{\sum{\text{x}}^2}}
\newcommand\sigmax{\ensuremath{\sigma{\text{x}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcinput}{m}
{
 \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hspace{0pt} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\def\onevarstats{\calcinput{1-Var\ Stats}}
\def\xbar{\calcinput{\ \txbar:1.23}}
\def\mysumx{\calcinput{\ \sumx:12}}
\def\mysumxsq{\calcinput{\ \sumxsq:140}}
\def\s{\calcinput{\ Sx:3.2}}
\def\mysigmax{\calcinput{\ \sigmax:2.2}}
\def\n{\calcinput{\ n:7}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large\ttfamily]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-4);
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (onevarstats) {\onevarstats};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (xbar) at (onevarstats.south west) {\xbar};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysumx) at (xbar.south west) {\mysumx};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysumxsq) at (mysumx.south west) {\mysumxsq};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (s) at (mysumxsq.south west) {\s};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysigmax) at (s.south west) {\mysigmax};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (n) at (mysigmax.south west) {\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 35):

Or alternatively you could use the following:

```
$\textstyle \sum$
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This does not really answer the question

Comment: Useful for me as I prefer ``\textstyle\sum`` to these other suggestions ``\scriptstyle\sum`` or ``\displaystyle\sum``, and it's a simple and ready solution.

Answer (score 22):

How about just using `\Sigma` instead of `\sum` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\tsurd{\ensuremath{\sqrt{\phantom{i}}}}
\newcommand\txbar{\ensuremath{\overline{\text{x}}}}
\newcommand\sumx{\ensuremath{\Sigma{\text{x}}}}
\newcommand\sumxsq{\ensuremath{\Sigma{\text{x}}^2}}
\newcommand\sigmax{\ensuremath{\sigma{\text{x}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\calcinput}{m}
{
 \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \hspace{0pt} }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\def\onevarstats{\calcinput{1-Var\ Stats}}
\def\xbar{\calcinput{\ \txbar:1.23}}
\def\mysumx{\calcinput{\ \sumx:12}}
\def\mysumxsq{\calcinput{\ \sumxsq:140}}
\def\s{\calcinput{\ Sx:3.2}}
\def\mysigmax{\calcinput{\ \sigmax:2.2}}
\def\n{\calcinput{\ n:7}}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\large\ttfamily]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-4);
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (onevarstats) {\onevarstats};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (xbar) at (onevarstats.south west) {\xbar};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysumx) at (xbar.south west) {\mysumx};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysumxsq) at (mysumx.south west) {\mysumxsq};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (s) at (mysumxsq.south west) {\s};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (mysigmax) at (s.south west) {\mysigmax};
\node[align=flush left,text width =5cm,
 anchor=north west,inner sep=1pt] (n) at (mysigmax.south west) {\n};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you could write `\scriptstyle\sum` in place of just `\sum`.

Comment: To expand on the last line: ``{\scriptstyle\sum}`` with curly brackets to restrict the shrinkage to the desired target.